# Sitecore SPEAK Basics

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7.1, sitecore-speak-ui

I am pretty new to Sitecore SPEAK and i am looking for some of the basics to start with. Basics like even which version of Sitecore Supports SPEAK. I see that  many places they mention that it is supported in 7.0 and few places say 7.1 version. I have a Sitecore 7.0 Version and when i open the Core database, i would like to know if i need to install any particular module as i dont see anything related to SPEAK.

This link is the sitecore's Official blog where they speak about it. But fail to mention the requirements. 
[Sitecore SPEAK Blog- Introduction](http://www.sitecore.net/Learn/Blogs/Technical-Blogs/Jakob-Christensen/Posts/2014/04/01-Speak-Introduction.aspx)
Any Help would be Greatly Appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [release notes](http://sdn.sitecore.net/Products/Sitecore%20V5/Sitecore%20CMS%207/ReleaseNotes/ChangeLog/Release%20History%20SC71.aspx), the SPEAK UI framework was introduced in Sitecore 7.1. At least you need this version and the [Sitecore Rocks Visual Studio plugin](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/44a26c88-83a7-46f6-903c-5c59bcd3d35b/), as building SPEAK applications are not very handy to build within the Content Editor.

Here you find a [summary of SPEAK documentations](http://sitecore-community.github.io/docs/documentation/Extending%20the%20Sitecore%20Client/index.html).

I would personally recommend to start with the [blog post series](http://mhwelander.net/category/speak/) from Martina Welander.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using the later versions of Sitecore 7.1 or preferably Sitecore 7.2. A lot of bugs have been fixed since the initial release of SPEAK.

I have two open source SPEAK applications, if you want to see examples of SPEAK applications are built.

https://github.com/sobek1985/SitecoreSPEAKBulkRolePermissions
https://github.com/sobek1985/SitecoreDataImporter

I have also created Visual Studio 2013 Templates for creating blank Visual Studio Projects for SPEAK.

https://github.com/sobek1985/SPEAKTemplatesForVisualStudio/releases